# How to use user information in multiple Apis?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have users, roles and permissions tables to use in my applications. At first I had a single web api that created using asp.net core. But later I need 3 web apis. So I write user account services in my first api. The service validates, create, delete, add to role, add to permission etc. so many operations. So I need similar operations in other new apis.

Which is the best way?

- I can copy account service codes to other project solutions. But any change occurs, I need to change all of them.
- If I create a common class library, controller and services are in different layers.

So I need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you with the second approach. There are two advantages, first, it will help you to reduce code redundancy, and can reuse the same code wherever needed in the application.

It also helps when you write test cases for your application. Separation of layers helps to develop the test layer easily.